# how to make the subview not to flash when the tableviewcell is selected

Tags: uitableview, animation, subview, iso

here is tableview cell

```
#import "ChannelCell.h"

@implementation ChannelCell
#pragma wipe the white space on the left
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
    [self.detailView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor ]];// 127 green:127 blue:127 alpha:0.7]];
    [self setHighlighted:FALSE];
}
@end
```

in the tableviewconrtroller,add the detailView:

```
 UIView *lineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cell.detailView.frame.size.height/2, cell.detailView.frame.size.height/2, cell.detailView.bounds.size.width/5*2, 1)];
    cell.detailView.alpha = 0.7;
    //[cell.detailView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed: 127 green:127 blue:127 alpha:0.7]];
    [cell.detailView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
    lineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    lineView.alpha = 0.5;
    //clock image
    //UIImageView *clockImageView =  [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.detailView.frame.size.width-self.detailView.frame.size.height,self.detailView.frame.size.height/4,  self.detailView.bounds.size.height/2, self.detailView.bounds.size.height/2)];
    UIButton *clockButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cell.detailView.frame.size.width-cell.detailView.frame.size.height,cell.detailView.frame.size.height/3,  cell.detailView.frame.size.height/3, cell.detailView.frame.size.height/3)];
    [clockButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"clock@2x.png"] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
    clockButton.alpha = 0.3;
    [clockButton setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    //tv program name
    UILabel* programNameLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cell.detailView.frame.size.height/2, cell.detailView.frame.size.height/3, cell.detailView.frame.size.width/5*1, cell.detailView.frame.size.height/2)];
    programNameLabel.alpha = 0.5;
    programNameLabel.text=@"TEST";
    [programNameLabel setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];

    [cell.detailView addSubview:programNameLabel];
    [cell.detailView addSubview:clockButton];
    [cell.detailView addSubview:lineView];
    [cell setHighlighted:NO];
```

here is the didSelectRowAtIndexPath

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"cell selected at index path %ld:%ld", (long)indexPath.section, (long)indexPath.row);

     if (!tableView.isEditing) {
        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
    }
}
```

eveytime when i click on the cell ,the subview flash.i just want the subview stay still,so [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO]; but it seems no to work. the subview disapperars for a very short time and appears again,just a flash. how could i remove this flash

Comment: thaks guys! i have solved this problem  remove     [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
 in the cell.m